# Java increment by 1 in a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to have the variable orderNum to increament for each order number by 1. Now this is in a switch statement i have tryed a for loop and orderNum++ but what is happing is orderNum just gives me 1 for each statement. So I'm not sure where i have gone wrong i have searched the net but can not find an answer yet.

Thank you for your help

```
public class orders extends javax.swing.JFrame{

private char productName;
private char productCode;
private double price;
private double discount;
private int quantity;
private double total;
private String message;
private int orderNum;
private final double MAXORDER = 1000;
private final double MINORDER = 0.1;

orders(char productCode, int quantity) {
 this.productCode = productCode;
 this.quantity = quantity;
 }
public String calculate() {
 double price = 0;
//int i = 0;
 String productName= " ";
 boolean isDiscounted = false;
 boolean isValidOrder = true;

 if (quantity > MAXORDER){
   message = "**ERROR** Invalid quantity. Quantity cannot be greater than 1000";
   isValidOrder = false;
    }
else if (quantity < MINORDER){
    message = "**ERROR** Invalid quantity. Quantity cannot be  0 or less ";
    isValidOrder = false;
}

 if (isValidOrder) {
 int orderNum =0;
 // while (i<100){ 
 switch (productCode) {
     case 'A':
         orderNum+=1;

         productName = "Pencil";
         price = quantity * 0.60;

         break;

     case 'b':
        orderNum+=1;

         productName = "Rubber";
         price = quantity * 0.90;

         break;

     case 'c':
         orderNum+=1;
         productName = "Meat";
         price = quantity * 100.00;

         break;

         default:
         isValidOrder = false;
         message = "Not this time";
         break;
        }

      if(isValidOrder){
     message = "Order Number: " + orderNum + "\n" + "You are buying " + productName +        "\n" + "The quantity of: " + quantity + "\n" + "For the price of $" + price;
     System.out.println("Tom is : " + orderNum);
     }
     }
// }
  return message;
  }   
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've just declared `orderNum` as 0, I think you wanted it as a class member. Also, I recommend `++` instead of `+= 1`. Something like

```
private static int orderNum = 0;

public String calculate() {
    double price = 0;
    // int i = 0;
    String productName = " ";
    boolean isDiscounted = false;
    boolean isValidOrder = true;

    if (quantity > MAXORDER) {
        message = "**ERROR** Invalid quantity. Quantity cannot be greater than 1000";
        isValidOrder = false;
    } else if (quantity < MINORDER) {
        message = "**ERROR** Invalid quantity. Quantity cannot be  0 or less ";
        isValidOrder = false;
    }

    if (isValidOrder) {
        // while (i<100){
        switch (productCode) {
        case 'A':
            orderNum++;
            productName = "Pencil";
            price = quantity * 0.60;
            break;
        case 'b':
            orderNum++;
            productName = "Rubber";
            price = quantity * 0.90;
            break;
        case 'c':
            orderNum++;
            productName = "Meat";
            price = quantity * 100.00;
            break;
        default:
            isValidOrder = false;
            message = "Not this time";
            break;
        }

        if (isValidOrder) {
            message = "Order Number: " + orderNum + "\n"
                    + "You are buying " + productName + "\n"
                    + "The quantity of: " + quantity + "\n"
                    + "For the price of $" + price;
            System.out.println("Tom is : " + orderNum);
        }
    }
    // }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining two `orderNum` variables: a class member field and a local variable inside the method. The local variable will always be initialized to zero for each method invokation so you need to remove it in order to increment the field variable.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help i knew it was something i had missed all good now

Answer (score 1):

You have [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the orderNum variable by declaring it after `if(isValidOrder)` , delete it and everything should be fine